# Google assitant won't find my Google Action any more

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

I have created a Google Action using Dialogflow and Google Actions Console. After I created my first alpha release I was able to use it both in my Android Phone & Android Auto, with this phone connected. However, it no more works.

1. I have 2 of my email addresses added to the alpha testers list.
2. I tried clicking on try now button from inviting listing.
3. I clicked on send to device and clicked on the push notification google send. I got a message "Sorry, I couldn't find that.".
4. I re-installed my assistant app in phone too.

However, in the action console, its says action is deployed. And I am getting this to work with Telegram. Its the action link that seems to be a problem.

Comment: Can you get it to work from a Google Assistant device that is logged into the Google Account that owns the Action?  What happens when you say "talk to my test app"?

Comment: @matthewayne I got the issue resolved. It's a tricky issue. I had two accounts, both had access to Dialogflow and Assistant console with right permission. It some how worked when I played around with the testing status in simulator. I disabled testing for all actions on all emails. And enabled testing for just this action on one email.

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  Its common practice to answer your own question if you figured the issue out, please do so if you found a solution to your issue!

Comment: I too had the very same problem. By using the test simulator on the specific version that was deployed has made it work. I no longer get the "Sorry, I coulnd't find that" response anymore.

Comment: @matthewayne I will be answering this in detail. I wanted some time to review the things I did. Will do it asap.